# Context.SaveChangesAsync() not working after Detached

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am working with EF Core and the logic is if any error occurs while saving then I write back the error to the database.

FYI: I am using Repository + UnitOfWork.

**Scenario 1** : Error occurs in `await _unitOfWork.CommitAsync();`

In the catch block first I am Detaching all the entities which have issues and unable to save, then adding a new entity to the error logging table and saving again by calling `await _unitOfWork.CommitAsync();` ***This is working as expected.***

**Scenario 2**: Error occurs `await _unitOfWork.ItemRepo.AddAsync(ss);` because of the `PK` violation.

Here also I am doing the same as above first Detaching then again saving, but `await _unitOfWork.CommitAsync();` not throwing any error, not returning the count of rows affected and also not inserting in the database.

That is why I am not able to figure out what's wrong happening here.

Edit: Adding the source code

```
public async Task<int> SaveAsync(List<ItemDTO> items)
    {
        try
        {          
            var ss = items.Select(x => new Item()
            {
                No = x.No,
                Description = x.Description,
                Type = x.Type,
                Price = x.Price                 
            });
            await _unitOfWork.ItemRepo.AddAsync(ss);                
            return await _unitOfWork.CommitAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            await SaveErrorAsync(e.Message,"");
            throw;
        }
    }

public async Task<int> SaveErrorAsync(string error, string type)
    {
        _unitOfWork.DetachAllEntities();
        await _unitOfWork.ErrorRepo.AddAsync(new Error()
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
            Type = type,
            Status = "Failed",
            Time = DateTime.UtcNow,
            StatusDescription = error
        });
        return await _unitOfWork.CommitAsync();
    }

 public void DetachAllEntities()
 {                
    _context.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Added ||
                e.State == EntityState.Modified ||
                e.State == EntityState.Deleted).ToList().ForEach(x => x.State = EntityState.Detached);
 }

public async Task<int> CommitAsync()
{            
    return await _context.SaveChangesAsync();            
}
```

Comment: _then adding a new entity to the error logging table_ - you haven't shown the code for that? Also, when it comes to calling `SaveChangesAsync` in the failing case, is the new entity actually in the context?

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
Also check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.

Comment: I don't understand why downvote. As per the suggestion, I have edited the question and included the complete source code. If anyone needs any other details then please comment

Comment: @stuartd I have edited the question and added the source code. And In the debug mode I have checked the new error entity exists in the context.

Comment: Any suggestions guys? I think many of us already working with Ef Core.